# Python pandas: How to match data between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### The first dataframe(df1) is similar to this:

| Result | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-31 | False | True | True |
| 2022-01-01 | False | False | True |
| 2022-01-02 | False | True | False |
| 2022-01-03 | True | False | True |

### df2 is an updated version of df1, the date data are new and the column names may be increased, which is similar to this:

| Result | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-04 | False | False | True | True |
| 2022-01-05 | True | False | True | True |
| 2022-01-06 | False | True | False | True |
| 2022-01-07 | False | False | True | True |

### I want to integrate two databases, but I don't know how to do it。
I want to get a result similar to the following:

| Result | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-31 | False | True | True | NaN |
| 2022-01-01 | False | False | True | NaN |
| 2022-01-02 | False | True | False | NaN |
| 2022-01-03 | True | False | True | NaN |
| 2022-01-04 | False | False | True | True |
| 2022-01-05 | True | False | True | True |
| 2022-01-06 | False | True | False | True |
| 2022-01-07 | False | False | True | True |

## **Thank you very much!**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the concatenate function while ignoring indexes

> df_new = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

Any missing values will be 'NaN'.